# How to show text into span In javascript with alphanumaric $("#abcd"+counter)

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to get value from **$.each**  and using counter for **HTML** entity `<span>`

```
var counter =1;
        $.each(catCounting, function(){
          alert(catCounting.(countCat+counter));
            $('#countCategory'+counter).html("("+catCounting.(countCat+counter)+")");
            counter++;
          });
        //alert(counter);
      }
```

Comment: What is `countCat`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure, but I believe you're trying to get the value at a specific index of `catCounting`. If this is the case, you need to use the index syntax to find the value which is `[]` rahter than `()`.

You don't need to use a `.` after the variable to do this, so `catCounting.(countCat + counter)` should become `catCounting[countCat + counter]`

```
var counter = 1;

$.each(catCounting, function(){
    alert(catCounting[countCat+counter]));

    $('#countCategory' + counter).html(
        "(" + catCounting[countCat + counter] + ")"
    );

    counter++;
});
```